# How do I migrate an older theme contribution to Qooxdoo 6.0?

Tags: qooxdoo

I've recently been asked whether it was possible for me to convert my older theme contributions to the new Qooxdoo packaging system. So I installed Qooxdoo 6.0 and got a first test app running - not without problems because the instructions in the official docs are a bit buggy (e.g "npx qx" is an unknown command with my Ubuntu 18.04). I also read about the packaging system and what to do to install one of the existing packages from the Qooxdoo repository.

Then I followed the steps described in section ["Create a new package"](https://qooxdoo.org/documentation/#/development/cli/packages?id=create-a-new-package). This procedure resulted in a folder structure which looked familiar at first sight, but a closer look made me wonder: There are two resource folders now, one is under "source" (as I would have expected) and the other one is under "source/class/[mypackage]". I also noticed that there is a "demo" folder in "source/class/[mypackage]", which used to be a top-level folder in previous Qooxdoo versions.

I then copied the theming files of my contribution to "source/class/theme", the demo app files to "source/class/[mypackage]/demo" and the demo resources to "source/class/[mypackage]/resource". After compiling the project I managed to run the demo app, but only without the expected resources (no icons, no fonts, no background images). The theming as such appears to be applied properly, but I keep getting plenty of error messages telling me "404 (Not found)" and "Image could not be loaded".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are running into a bug with our template for packages ... please open an issue https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo-compiler/issues/

As for how to do it. Have a look at an actual theme package for 6.0 https://github.com/ITISFoundation/qx-osparc-theme there you can see the required structure.

Also, for this kind of question, interactive help is probably best. Visit the qooxdoo chat on https://gitter.im/qooxdoo/qooxdoo

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to you sparc theme, I used it as template to rearrange the folder structure of my own theme. This way I managed to get at least the Qoxdoo icons loaded, but I still can't figure out how to include the theme specific icons and images as well as the fonts used by the demo application properly ("404 (Not found)" and "Image could not be loaded").

Comment: BTW: I will definitely NOT use "qooxdoo chat" for communication about problems like this, I'd rather abandon qooxdoo instead. What happened to the mailing list anyway?